# add labels to non-zero elements in stacked column chart Excel 2013

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2013, label

I'm generating a stacked column chart out of an a table like this:

```
Year 1   2    3
A    50  0    0
B    50  0    0
C    0   100  0
D    0   50   0
E    0   0   10
F    0   0   15
```

I want column stacks for every year, with series labels for every non-zero value. Currently if I try and add labels then I get 6 labels for every series (with the zero values clustered around the axis). How do I generate series labels for all non-zeroes? I am happy to rearrange my data to a different format to the table above. I am using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw an error to replace the zeros in your data. That way they won't appear on your chart. You can use:

```
=NA()
```